# Playing Vimeo videos in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, vimeo, flutter-web

I'm trying to play **vimeo videos** in flutter app using the `video_player` plugin but got **no success**, it's throwing bunch of errors. 
please help me how I might go about implementing this in flutter app? using webview or any plugin etc? perhaps a code snippet would be huge help for me!

here is my code snippet

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoApp());

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://vimeo.com/{some-video-id}')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _controller.value.initialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

**THE ERROR IN DEBUG CONSOLE -**

> E/AccessibilityBridge(28662): VirtualView node must not be the root
>   node. E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28662): Source error.
>   E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28662):
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException:
>   Response code: 404 E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28662):    at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:300)
>   E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28662):   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
>   E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28662):   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:885)
>   E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28662):   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:381)
>   E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28662):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>   E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28662):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>   E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(28662):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

Comment: Please, provide code example that explain what you try to do.

Comment: @Abjox i've updated my question, please have a look at it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The video_player plugin is for playing video files directly, which means you need a direct URL to the video file itself. You aren't going to be able to just give it the URL of some random site where a video happens to be on the page somewhere, because it won't know what to do with that.

Comment: thanks for your response @Abion47  is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm deeply in need to integrate vimeo in my flutter app, please let me know if it can be achieved or not?

Comment: There aren't any plugins for Vimeo videos that I can find so your only option is probably to use a web view to embed the video player into.

Comment: thanks @Abion47, can you please provide me with any example on how to use webview to embed vimeo? i'm a newbie to flutter, it would be a huge help for me. thanks again!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cant use Vimeo URL [https://vimeo.com/{some-video-id}](https://vimeo.com/%7Bsome-video-id%7D). `VideoPlayerController` requires the streamable video URL.

> Solution 1

**Required premium account of Vimeo**

1. go to https://vimeo.com/manage/ and select the video you want to play
2. select the distribution tab from the left side panel.
3. select video file link
4. select the play video.. copay the video link(its the mp4 stealable video link)..use this URL for `VideoPlayerController`.

   [image]

> Solution 2

**Video link will expire in every 15 mins**

1. call the API [https://player.vimeo.com/video/{video_id}/config](https://player.vimeo.com/video/382169007/config) you will get the JSON response.
   [image]
2. progressive object you will get mp4 video url .

> Solution 3

1. Replace the video controller with `webivew` give this url
   https://vimeo.com/{some-video-id} ..enable the javascript, video
   will play in webview .

Comment: I have created a test version of a vimeo player. Feel free to fork and modify! https://github.com/ThuAbLKA/flutter-vimeo-player

Comment: @Rahul Devanavar    I am using Solution 1: PRO members have access to direct video file links. As is know Vimeo does not support, nor recommend using URLs. Do they change URLs without any prior notification even for PRO members?

Comment: Thank you, trying the second solution but the config API is not responding to private videos even with private links, any workaround

Thanks again

Comment: is there any option available to play private Vimeo video?

Comment: Yes you can use config api

Answer (score 0):

Install vimeoplayer: ^0.1.8 on pubspec

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Video EasyRider')),
       body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
          VimeoPlayer(id: '123456789', autoPlay: false),
        ]));
  }
```

Comment: pub dev is here: [https://pub.dev/packages/vimeoplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/vimeoplayer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use vimeo_player_flutter package to achieve this. It is easy & supports Android and IOS platforms. It works based on webview.

Refer this [link](https://youtu.be/3zzil4XEUBw) for more details on this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31563168)